# How to find fid from cid in google place?

Tags: google-maps, google-places

I need `"fid"` of google place if I have `"cid"`

```
CID: 13044706322416579131
FID: 0x395e84f3f650771d:0xb5081b4952eeb23b
```

As I found 2nd portion `(0xb5081b4952eeb23b)` of `fid` is hex of `cid` `(13044706322416579131)`.

But I can't find how to get 1st portion `(0x395e84f3f650771d)`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm looking at accomplishing the same thing. I have the place_id and the CID, but I'd like to find the FID programmatically.

Comment: Right now I found temporary solution to just put 0 in first part of fid. 
But in this site, in backend they use some logic, I can't figure out that. pleper.com/index.php?do=tools&sdo=google_review_link

Answer (score 0):

First, you would start by locating the Google Plus Local page.

You then click the ‘Edit business details’ link on that G+ Local Page. That URL can then be transposed into a Google Maps (Google Places) URL such as in this example:

- visit a Google+ Local page, such as: https://plus.google.com/109929267125901378263/
- click ‘Edit business details’ on the G+ Local page
- copy the first part of the URL on the page that appears after clicking on ‘Edit business details’.
- paste the URL into a text file and you end up with a URL similar to this (but longer): https://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=4851990417008427082&mode=edit […]
- remove the text: /place … and remove anything after the CID # (meaning: remove ‘&mode’ and anything after it)

You end up with a Google Maps URL such as this, which you can bookmark for reference sake: https://maps.google.com/maps?cid=4851990417008427082.  You would then finish the process by doing this:

- copy the part that says cid=################### and paste it after this partial URL: www.google.com/mapmaker?gw=90&
- the result is a Google Map Maker URL such as: www.google.com/mapmaker?gw=90&cid=4851990417008427082 (I call that the ‘gw 90’ GMM POI URL.)

However, it is often useful to have another version of the URL in the format of: www.google.com/mapmaker?gw=39&fid=.  (I call that the ‘GW 39’ or the ‘FID’ version of the GMM POI) such as this: www.google.com/mapmaker?gw=39&fid=0x8804fe4c222357a7:0x692b02e73b5dc33b

Referred from [here](http://www.orionweb.net/blog/how-to-find-fid-version-of-google-map-maker-poi-url-from-gmm-cid-version/).

Comment: As in my website any user insert cid and I want automatic generate a specific url which need fid.
So I want any google API or any method to get `fid` from inserted `cid`.

Comment: After searching deeper, Unfortunately I was not able to find any method or API associated with this.

Comment: Thanks @AniV,
Right now I found temporary solution to just put `0` in first part of `fid`.

But in this site, in backend they use some logic, I can't fetch that.
http://pleper.com/index.php?do=tools&sdo=google_review_link