# Retrieving Google FID From Google Places

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

I'm would like to programmatically retrieve the Google `FID` for a certain Google Place. I can successfully retrieve the `Place ID` and the `CID` for a location, but I can't seem to find the `FID`.

For example, I have a business with the following information:

**Business Name:** Adobe - Lehi — 3900 Adobe Way , Lehi, UT

**Google Place ID:** ChIJ6-G_3DqAUocRw5ctKLeX2yI

**Google CID:** 2511768030098069443

Now I would like to find the `FID` for this location, which in this case is `0x8752803adcbfe1eb:0x22db97b7282d97c3`

The `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json` endpoint doesn't return the `FID` and I'm not sure where else I could look.

I used [this tool](https://www.grade.us/home/labs/google-review-link-generator) to generate the `FID`, but I'd like to be able to do this on my own site on my own server with my own code. I'd like to be able to do this for many businesses, so a manual approach just won't do. Any Suggestions?

References:

https://www.grade.us/home/labs/google-review-link-generator

[How to find fid from cid in google place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128685/how-to-find-fid-from-cid-in-google-place)

https://www.sunant.com/robots-and-rockets-blog/how-to-find-fid-version-of-google-map-maker-poi-url-from-gmm-cid-version/

https://pleper.com/index.php?do=tools&sdo=google_review_link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is in the example grade.us website you posted. The top link for Google Review dialog looks like this:

http://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=ChIJ65TE6LocdkgRiHsKkgh7yTU

But when clicked the browser redirects to:

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Electricity+Showrooms,+39A+Hoxton+Square,+London+N1+6NN&ludocid=3875764231069137800#lrd=0x48761cbae8c494eb:0x35c97b08920a7b88,3

You'll notice the **lrd** parameter before the comma is the FID you are looking for. Therefore, use whatever your programming language HTTP requests module is to get the redirection response when submitting the 'writereview' URL.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed!